# Laravel ServiceProvider Class not found in package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, laravel-artisan

I have installed Laravel 5.4 latest vesion in my Windows 7 64Bit, Uwamp local server.

I have already created following files in my "Custom" package that I am trying to register in Laravel:

**packages/custom/timeshow/composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "custom/timeshow",
    "description": "Show Time in All Timezones",
    "type": "composer-plugin",
    "license": "GPL",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Test Author",
            "email": "test1234@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Custom\\Timeshow\\": "packages/custom/timeshow/src"
        }
    }
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

**packages\custom\timeshow\src\TimeshowServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Timeshow;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TimeshowServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
        $this->app->make('Custom\Timeshow\TimeshowController');
    }
}
```

**packages\custom\timeshow\src\TimeshowController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Timeshow;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class TimeshowController extends Controller
{
    public function index($timezone)
    {
        echo Carbon::now($timezone)->toDateTimeString();
    }
}
```

**packages\custom\timeshow\src\routes.php**

```
<?php
Route::get('timeshow/{timezone}', 'Custom\Timeshow\TimeshowController@index');
```

Also included my service-provider in **config/app.php** like below:

```
Custom\Timeshow\TimeshowServiceProvider::class,
```

But even after all this, when I run the command `php artisan serve`, I get the below error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Custom\Timeshow\TimeshowServiceProvider' not found
```

Can someone point out what is wrong in this and assit in resolving it ?

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` command.

Comment: Just... do This ...  php artisan vendor:publish ..

Comment: Did many times, even with `-o` parameter, eveytime it says "Generated ... successfully", but after that same error.

Comment: and then php artisan serve .... try

Comment: Same error when I run `php artisan vendor:publish`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can call app->make() on your provider just yet. Register it first in the AppServiceProvier's register() method like:

```
$this->app->register(Custom\Timeshow\TimeshowServiceProvider::class);
```

After that you should be able to resolve it out of the application container. Alternatively you can call:

```
$this->app->singleton(Custom\Timeshow\TimeshowServiceProvider::class, function (Application $app) {
    return new TimeshowServiceProvider();
});
```

within your package service provider. I typically bind singleton instances in the packages I write.

**edit**

Another thought, add your package namespace to your application composer.json as well:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Custom\\Timeshow\\": "packages/custom/timeshow/src"
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I did that and was able to get past that error, but when I run the following URL in browser - `http://localhost:8000/packagetest/public/timeshow/UTC`, I am not getting the current time converted to UTC timezone, can you help with that ?

Comment: Why do you have packagetest/public in your url? Is that your document root configured in your web server?

Comment: How do you normally access your laravel application? Just at http://localhost:8000/? If everything is correct your package routes should like up with the standard routing paths the laravel app takes.

Comment: Yes it works with regular Laravel path with http://localhost:8000/timeshow/UTC, I was following this tutorial http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-a-laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps/ "packagetest" url was mentioned, but now I got it, thanks a lot for your help. About the first alternative in your answer, do I need to bind the singleton instance of service provider in my package's service provider's `boot` method ?

Answer (score 1):

after adding custom package to composer you should run below command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
php artisan optimize
```